# Power BI Measure returning Blank when it shouldn't

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax

I am trying to create a measure that will return a value for the number of issued receipts in the year 2020:

```
CALCULATE(SUM(Receipts[issued]), FILTER(Receipts, Receipts[Year] = 2020))
```

However, the measure keeps returning blank, even as a calculated column.

I've also tried

```
CALCULATE(SUM(Receipts[issued]), FILTER(Receipts, Receipts[Year].Year = 2020))
```

But that is returning an error saying the syntax for "Year" is incorrect.

[image]

The Year column is of datatype Date and is linked to a dimDate table on the Date column.

I am trying to retrieve the value 440,000. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the error shown? What is the datatype of Receipts[Year]?

Comment: As stated in the question, there is no error in the first DAX example, it's just a blank value, and the second says "The syntax for "Year" is incorrect".  The datatype is Date.

Comment: There is your problem. If the datatype is date, then "= 2020" is not a date. What is the actual value in the column if the date is date. Have you tried "YEAR(Receipts[Year]) = 2020"

Comment: That did it. I really wish Power BI's error reporting would be smart enough to see that as a solution. Thank you.

Comment: Good stuff. I'll add it as an answer so you can mark as solved. BTW, you should not filter entire tables. I'll give you a better syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
CALCULATE(SUM(Receipts[issued]),  YEAR(Receipts[Year]) = 2020)
```